# How do I make EditorFor conditionally readonly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this line of code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

I have a variable in my view data dictionary called Readonly. How do I make Quantity read-only if `ViewBag.Readonly` is true and not read only if it is false?

Simple thing, but the combination of Razor with HTML (which is ancient) makes otherwise simple things impossible.

**Edits:**

I don't want to use an if statement. That is a last resort because it violates DRY which I have been severely burned many times in the past for not following.

The line I have above does work insofar as it makes the text box read-only. I need to make this conditional based upon my view state.

**Solution:**

I've used the following. It still is a DRY violation, but it reduces it to one line.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = ViewBag.Readonly ? (object)new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "htmlsucks" } : (object)new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today I had to deal with this issue as I had to dynamically set a "readonly" attribute to a `Html.TextBoxFor` element. I ended up writing the following helper method which allowed me to workaround the issue while keeping a DRY approach:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets an object containing a htmlAttributes collection for any Razor HTML helper component,
/// supporting a static set (anonymous object) and/or a dynamic set (Dictionary)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fixedHtmlAttributes">A fixed set of htmlAttributes (anonymous object)</param>
/// <param name="dynamicHtmlAttributes">A dynamic set of htmlAttributes (Dictionary)</param>
/// <returns>A collection of htmlAttributes including a merge of the given set(s)</returns>
public static IDictionary<string, object> GetHtmlAttributes(
    object fixedHtmlAttributes = null,
    IDictionary<string, object> dynamicHtmlAttributes = null
    )
{
    var rvd = (fixedHtmlAttributes == null)
        ? new RouteValueDictionary()
        : HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(fixedHtmlAttributes);
    if (dynamicHtmlAttributes != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dynamicHtmlAttributes)
            rvd[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
    }
    return rvd;
}
```

It can be used in the following way:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string,object>();
if (IsReadOnly()) dic.Add("readonly", "readonly");
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, GetHtmlAttributes(new { @class="someclass" }, dic))
```

The code is quite self-explanatory, however I also explained the underlying logic in [this post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-mvc-dinamically-set-htmlattributes-razor-html-helpers-readonly/) on my blog.

Comment: Still fairly ugly razor code, but I can work with this. Thanks, Instead of a dictionary I would probably create a translation layer that would change `readonly=true` to `readonly="readonly"` and remove `readonly=false` so that read-only could be set to a Boolean value. 

Stupid HTML spec with your valueless attributes! This is why we normalize interfaces. I wish I could go back in time and slap somebody sometimes.

Comment: @Jordan , the main advantage of this workaround is that it can also be used to dinamically set other property-setting and/or valued attributes (including, yet not limiting to, readonly).

Comment: Right, but the problem with the OP was with with valueless attributes which is rather small set. The only ones I can think of are `readonly` and `disabled`. These are the only real problems if you think about it. They are the only attributes that you cannot just leave blank.

Answer (score 32):

**EDIT: MVC 5**

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Readonly=true;//false
```

**View**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, ViewBag.Readonly ? (object)new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" }} : new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Nice. I see how you minimized the DRY violation. I respect that. I've changed things a little but I think I'll use this. I still hope for a better options, but this works for now.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: the problem of this is when you have a large set of `htmlAttributes`, you have to repeat all the others ***just to switch the readonly***??? And it's even worse when you have other attributes (similar to readonly) to switch together independently, such as `disabled`, `required`, ... So suppose the number of such attributes is `n`, you need `2^n` expressions with ***duplicated settings*** for other attributes. That's a terrible design. The best design in this case is if the property is set to `null`, just ignore rendering it. ASP.NET MVC still need more improvement.

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple. Do it like this.

```
@if((bool)ViewBag.Readonly)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
}
else
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}
```

Comment: You can pass html attributes to `Html.EditorFor` in MVC5 (I should have been clearer about which version of MVC I am using.) The code I have above does make the text box read only. I do not know how to make that conditional without an if statement (again should have been clearer, sorry).

Comment: Why don't you want to use an `if` statement?

Comment: No problem. I have been burned in the past by not following the DRY principle. A single two part if statement with very simple content seems like no big deal, but it can grow as you modify code over time. I will do this if no other solution presents itself, but this just seems like a weakness in the speck not to be able to do this. HTML should use readonly='true|false' not this name-only attribute nonsense that they still have.

Comment: And it is REALLY ugly code to have if statement's like that everywhere you want to do something as simple as make a field conditionally read-only. I like my code to be human readable. I may see if I can hack the integer template and do this myself to avoid that situation. I'll have to figure out how to do that. ...

Comment: I agree that it's ugly. But, there's no other option. Unless, you want to use AngularJS, which I think is totally unnecessary if you want to use it for this purpose only.

Comment: You can also make it read-only by default and remove the `readonly` attribute by jQuery only if `ViewBag.Readonly` is false.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have many places in your view with such logic, I think using the library [FluentDataAnnotations](https://github.com/alexanderar/FluentDataAnnotations/) can keep you code clean and clear.

If you are familiar with [FluentValidator](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation), it's very similar using.

In your case all the logic will moved from a view to model annotation class. In you will have only `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)`

It even allows to use model properties in conditions 
e.g. 
`this.When(model => !model.AllowEditPhone,
 () => {
     this.For(m => m.Phone).SetReadOnly(false);
 });`

Here the [NuGet package](https://packages.nuget.org/packages/FluentDataAnnotations.Mvc/) that requires ASP.NET MVC 5. 
(Support for ASP.NET Core are in progress.)

Answer (score 1):

By writing a helper method the DRY principal can be respected.

```
    using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

    public static MvcHtmlString Concat(this MvcHtmlString first, params MvcHtmlString[] strings)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(first.ToString() + string.Concat(strings.Select(s => ( s == null ? "" : s.ToString()))));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString ConditionalEditFor<TModel,TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, bool EditCondition, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> Expression)
    {
        helper.ConditionalEditFor(EditCondition,Expression,false);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString ConditionalEditFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, bool EditCondition, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> Expression, bool IncludeValidationOnEdit)
    {
        if (EditCondition)
        {
            if (!IncludeValidationOnEdit)
                return EditorExtensions.EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(helper, Expression);
            else
                return EditorExtensions.EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(helper, Expression).Concat(ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TValue>(helper, Expression));
        }
        else
        {
            return DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(helper, Expression);
        }
    }
```

then in your view:

add a conditional statement to determine readonly
e.g.

```
@{bool IsReadOnly = YourCondition;}

@Html.ConditionalEditFor(!IsReadOnly/*condition*/, model => model.YourProperty,true /*do validation*/)
```

you can then add whatever other overrides you want.

Answer (score 1):

JQUERY to read SETUP_TYPE control value and disable controls with a particular CSS selector.

```
$(function () {
    if ($("#SETUP_TYPE").val() == "1") { $('.XXX').attr('disabled', true); }
})

$(function () {
    if ($("#SETUP_TYPE").val() == "2") { $('.YYY').attr('disabled', true); }
})
```

This control is disabled if SETUP_TYPE is 1 or 2.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CLAIM, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control XXX YYY" } })
```

This control is disabled if SETUP_TYPE is 1.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.POLICY, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control XXX" } })
```

This control is disabled if SETUP_TYPE is 2.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.INSURED, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control YYY" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a an IHtmlHelper extension with additional parameters:

```cs
public static IHtmlContent ReadonlyishTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null, bool shouldBeReadonly = false)
{
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if (htmlAttributes != null)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in htmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            attributes.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(htmlAttributes));
        }
    }

    if (shouldBeReadonly)
    {
        attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    }

    return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, format: null, attributes);
}
```

Razor:

```cs
@Html.ReadonlyishTextBoxFor(p => p.Email, new { @class = "form-control" }, true )
@Html.ReadonlyishTextBoxFor(p => p.Email, new { @class = "form-control" } )
```